# Custom progressbar dialog with dialogFragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, customdialog, dialogfragment

I'm new to android programming. I want to create a custom progress dialog with some textview and button and showing the progress with **two progressBar** and updating them while sending the files from **Asynctask**, Also I want it works with minimum API 10. google doc recommend me to use **DialogFragment** and i do not have any idea how to update the progress bars and textviews that are in that custom layout of my fragmentDialog, when I try to reference a textview or progress bar it throw null exeption

Here is my code

```
public static class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public FireMissilesDialogFragment(){
    }
    public static FireMissilesDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        FireMissilesDialogFragment frag = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_progress, null);
        ProgressBar pbCurrent = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.current);

        builder.setView(view);

        builder.setMessage("Fire Missiles")
        .setPositiveButton("Fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User cancelled the dialog
            }
        });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I got a nullExeption here in my main activity when try to reference a view

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button frag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.frag);
    frag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FireMissilesDialogFragment fragment = FireMissilesDialogFragment.newInstance("hi") ;
            fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.current);// nullExeption here
            //              downloadAsync as = new downloadAsync();
            //              as.execute();

        }
    });
```

I didn't see much question and example about that, did I go all the way wrong and should pick another way to achieve my point??!!

Edit : 
I'm trying to create something like [this](http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim2/2013/05/09/ES_File_Explorer-_share_files.png)

thanks in advance

Comment: progressbar belongs to the fragment. if you initialize it in activity you end up in nullpointerexception. you can have asynctask invoked in fragment itself

Comment: I'm really new to android programming. could you help me what should I do? I would appreciated if it includes a sample code...

Comment: read the docs on fragment and asynctask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not do a full explanation but I can leave an example and then hopefully you can figure out a way to incorporate the things you need.

The DialogFragment with an AsyncTask and a Progress bar:

```
public class LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment.class
            .getSimpleName();

    public interface LoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback {
        void onPreExecute(int maxProgress);

        void onProgressUpdate(int progress);

        void onCancelled();

        void onPostExecute();
    }

    private LoadHydrantsToMapTask mTask;
    // private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private List<HydrantHolder> mHydrants;

    private GoogleMap map;

    public static LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment newInstance(
            List<HydrantHolder> hydrants, GoogleMap map) {
        LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment taskFragment = new LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment();
        taskFragment.mHydrants = hydrants;
        taskFragment.map = map;

        return taskFragment;
    }

    @Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress_task, container);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        mProgressBar.setMax(mHydrants.size());

        getDialog().setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.adding_hydrants));
        // This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key.
        getDialog().setCancelable(false);
        getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * This method will only be called once when the retained Fragment is first
     * created.
     */
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(SherlockDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.TuriosDialog);

        // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
        setRetainInstance(true);

        mTask = new LoadHydrantsToMapTask(mHydrants);
        mTask.setCallback(new LoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback() {

            @Override public void onPreExecute(int maxProgress) {
            }

            @Override public void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }

            @Override public void onPostExecute() {
                if (isResumed())
                    dismiss();

                mTask = null;

            }

            @Override public void onCancelled() {
                if (isResumed())
                    dismiss();

                mTask = null;
            }
        });

        mTask.execute();
    }

    @Override public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // This is a little hacky, but we will see if the task has finished
        // while we weren't
        // in this activity, and then we can dismiss ourselves.
        if (mTask == null)
            dismiss();
    }

    @Override public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    // This is to work around what is apparently a bug. If you don't have it
    // here the dialog will be dismissed on rotation, so tell it not to dismiss.
    @Override public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getDialog() != null && getRetainInstance())
            getDialog().setDismissMessage(null);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    // Also when we are dismissed we need to cancel the task.
    @Override public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onDismiss(dialog);
        // If true, the thread is interrupted immediately, which may do bad
        // things.
        // If false, it guarantees a result is never returned (onPostExecute()
        // isn't called)
        // but you have to repeatedly call isCancelled() in your
        // doInBackground()
        // function to check if it should exit. For some tasks that might not be
        // feasible.
        if (mTask != null)
            mTask.cancel(false);

    }

    private class LoadHydrantsToMapTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<MarkerOptions>> {
        // Before running code in separate thread
        List<HydrantHolder> mHydrants;
        LoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback;

        public LoadHydrantsToMapTask(List<HydrantHolder> hydrants) {
            this.mHydrants = hydrants;
        }

        public void setCallback(
                LoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback loadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback) {
            this.mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback = loadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback;
        }

        @Override protected void onPreExecute() {

            if (mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback != null) {
                mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback.onPreExecute(mHydrants.size());
            }

        }

        // The code to be executed in a background thread.
        @Override protected List<MarkerOptions> doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            List<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();

            for (HydrantHolder hydrant : mHydrants) {

                final String hydrant_type = hydrant.getHydrantType();
                final String hydrant_icon_path = hydrant.getIconPath();
                double latitude = hydrant.getLatitude();
                double longitude = hydrant.getLongitude();

                final LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                final String address = hydrant.getAddress();
                final String addressNumber = hydrant.getAddressNumber();
                final String addressremark = hydrant.getAddressRemark();
                final String remark = hydrant.getRemark();

                // Log.d(TAG, hydrant.toString());

                BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);

                if (!hydrant_icon_path.isEmpty()) {
                    File iconfile = new File(hydrant_icon_path);
                    if (iconfile.exists()) {
                        BitmapDescriptor loaded_icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromPath(hydrant_icon_path);
                        if (loaded_icon != null) {
                            icon = loaded_icon;
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "loaded_icon was null");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "iconfile did not exist: "
                                + hydrant_icon_path);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "iconpath was empty on hydrant type: "
                            + hydrant_type);
                }

                StringBuffer snippet = new StringBuffer();
                if (!address.isEmpty())
                    snippet.append("\n" + address + " " + addressNumber);
                if (addressremark.isEmpty())
                    snippet.append("\n" + addressremark);
                if (!remark.isEmpty())
                    snippet.append("\n" + remark);

                markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(position)
                        .title(hydrant_type).snippet(snippet.toString())
                        .icon(icon));

                publishProgress(markers.size());
            }
            return markers;
        }

        // Update the progress
        @Override protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            if (mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback != null) {
                mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback.onProgressUpdate(values[0]);
            }
        }

        @Override protected void onCancelled() {
            if (mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback != null) {
                mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback.onCancelled();
            }
        }

        // after executing the code in the thread
        @Override protected void onPostExecute(List<MarkerOptions> markers) {

            for (MarkerOptions marker : markers) {
                if (marker != null && map != null)
                    map.addMarker(marker);
            }

            if (mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback != null) {
                mLoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback.onPostExecute();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

My dialog_progress_task layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:maxHeight="10dip"
        android:minHeight="10dip"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_orange" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the code I use to add it:

```
@Override public void loadHydrantsToMap(List<HydrantHolder> hydrants,
        GoogleMap map) {

    LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment loadHydrantsFragment;

    if (fm != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        loadHydrantsFragment = (LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment) fm
                .findFragmentByTag(LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment.TAG);
        if (loadHydrantsFragment != null) {
            Log.i("Attatching LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment");
            ft.attach(loadHydrantsFragment);
        } else {
            loadHydrantsFragment = LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment
                    .newInstance(hydrants, map);
            Log.i("Adding new LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment");
            ft.add(loadHydrantsFragment, LoadHydrantsToMapTaskFragment.TAG);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but it looks to complicated to me. I should put some time on it...

Comment: Yeah I know it is quite a lot, also why I could not see a smart way to condense it as a general example. Thought, you can forget most of the AsyncTask, especially doInBackground(..). The most important part is 1) newInstance takes the arguments to be loaded 2) LoadHydrantsToMapTaskCallback (perhaps rename to just loadCallback) keeps track of the progress of AsyncTask 3) mTask.setCallback(..) react to the callbacks by updating the UI

Comment: I red your code but I didn't find out when the dialog pops up!!?? could you please edit it a little bit. BTW I find this `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransaction()` after showing the dialog in an activity that does what I need, but being said we should avoid of doing that... thx

Comment: Im not sure what you mean? The dialog should pop up when the fragment is added ft.add(yourdialogfragment,"sometag").commit(); and dismiss itself when the loading is complete.

Comment: After of 3 hours of coding I made it. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem :) took me a while too but is nice to have since it handles orientation changes and everything.